# No default application is opening

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

I was recently looking for some ways to speed up my system and I installed lubuntu on top of my Ubuntu system. Since then none of my default apps are working. The terminal, Files Explorer and many more they are not opening on clicking them. Any suggestions on how I can resolve the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "installed on top"?

Comment: I'm guessing the poster installed *lubuntu-desktop* on the existing system.

Comment: Yes, @DKBose is right.

Comment: Lubuntu with it's default apps is faster than Ubuntu (gnome), hut Lubuntu with LXDE (18.04) use older libraries requiring less memory; however if you use a a gnome intended app you'll end up causing both older GTK+2 (for LXDE) & GTK+3 (GNOME app) libraries to be in memory and you could find no speed increase. LXDE and its use of GTK+2 was never modernized; instead Lubuntu moved to LXQt (Qt libs in 18.10).  My point is what you have attempted to do may not have sped up your machine at all, with it depending on how you used it.

Comment: Myself, I like having multiple desktops on my desktop (I can choose at login which I want to use on my decade old box) so I do it, but I try to remember if using LXDE to use `leafpad` instead of `gedit`, `pcmanfm` instead of `nautilus` etc which may take some getting used to.  In your case you may have a problem, and I'd suggest logging out & logging into gnome (select it at login) & checking a terminal will load (I'd ideally suggest loading apps from terminal, which you say currently you can't do to view messages). Is your machine [hdd] thrashing? (ie. hdd light on & busy) or ...

Comment: How to check for HDD Thrashing?